# Getting many location updates

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I'm implementing user location for IOS using swift. This is my code.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class localizationViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 500
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0 {

                let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            } else {
                println("Error with data")
            }
        })
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        var city = placemark.locality
        var department = placemark.administrativeArea
        var country = placemark.country
        var latitude = placemark.location.coordinate.latitude
        var longitude = placemark.location.coordinate.longitude
        var date = placemark.location.timestamp

        println(city)
        println(department)
        println(country)
        println(latitude)
        println(longitude)
        println(date)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using    segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */


    @IBAction func actionLocation(sender: UISwitch) {
        println("get location request")
    }
}
```

I'm getting the location info properly, but, always updates 3 or 4 times. I was reading that if you set the distanceFilter this stops but, it's not working for me. How can I configure my didUpdateLocations for get only one location per request? How can i run this function inside an action element (switct or button per example)? This last question because maybe the reason is that always, on the first location request, the app doesn't take the vaules of Accuary a distancefilter... Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` inside your `actionLocation()` function, so that it will start getting new locations after you press a button.

The `distanceFilter` is to specify the minimum update distance in meters. If you set the value to 500, it will only update every 500 meters you move. By default, `kCLDistanceFilterNone` is used. Pass in `kCLDistanceFilterNone` to be notified of all movements.

You can use a Bool value before your Geocoder, and change the Bool value after or inside your `displayLocationInfo` method

```
if updating == false {
  updating = true

CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(locations.last as CLLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarkers, error:NSError!) -> Void in 
  .....
   self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
   self.updating = false
})
}
```

In your `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)` You should do a `println(locations.count)` to check how many locations it returns. If there is more than one locations returned, you usually use the last one.

So you should change your `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in` to use `locations.last`, so you can do `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(locations.last as CLLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarkers, error:NSError!) -> Void in` instead.